# Adding a filter to a transaction (work order) search for multiple transaction ids

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am building a search in a RESTlet.  I am stuck on creating an elegant filter based upon `transactionumber`.  I would like to filter it with an **ANYOF** operator, passing in an array of numbers for values, but that does not seem possible.

The only solution I have found is to pre-process the array into a string of numbers and use a conditional SQL function to test it:

```
search.createFilter({
    name : 'formulanumeric',
    formula :  'case when TO_NUMBER({transactionnumber}) in (' 
        + tranids.join(',')   // e.g.   in (741,744)  
        + ') then 1 else 0 end',
    operator : search.Operator.NOTEQUALTO,
    values : 0
});
```

**Surely there is a better way.**  The above has a (slight) performance hit of converting the array to a string and I'm concerned about limitations of the formulanumeric field -- i.e. length of the formula string.

Answer (score -1):

**transactionnumber** is a text field, so you cannot use *anyof* operator as you are trying to use. You will have to use *is* with filterExpressions and joining them with *or* operator.

You could try something like below

```
transactionNumbersList = ['abc', 'xyz'];

var searchFilters = [];

transactionNumbersList.forEach(function (transactionNumber) {
  searchFilters.push(['transactionnumber', 'is', transactionNumber], 'or')
});

// pop trailing `or`
searchFilters.pop();
```

Comment: This does not work: tranid and transactionnumber are not the same field nor the same data type

Comment: @gillyspy sorry I didn't check you were trying to use `transactionnumber`, since in your example you seem to be using param named `tranids`. I've updated my answer.